# PHP JSON encode to utf8 and print it

Tags: php, json

The following is my php script:

```
<?php


$con = $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("ninelifes", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY quotations DESC LIMIT 21,1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[]= $row;
  }

print json_encode($output);

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

This is the print:

[image]

The "\u00e4" is a "ä". Well, the question is how can is solve the utf8 decoding for my json print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Read more about [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters) parameters.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this fast reply! <3

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept the answer if was helpful for you.